# A Border around multiple Grid items without additional container?

Tags: css, border, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to understand a correct way to do this kind of thing in Grid. As I'm unsure if I'm doing it right.

As question suggest, primarly it as about Bordering around Grid items without additional container. However, if you are here, after reading the title of the question, you are appreciated to contribute or improve
in any possible way.

## The Idea|Problem

[Straight forward example of how everything should look after problem is solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQji.png)

I need to make a single column **Grid** layout with items:

- Header
- Main
- Footer

That should be centered on the browser.

**Then** there should be a single border around all these three items.

Also, a layout must have ability to expand in **heigh** as more items are added into `<main>` element.

### Limitations:

1. Without creating additional container.
2. Without using border Individual Sides properties

   - border-top
   - border-right
   - border-bottom
   - border-left

---

What I have done and tried so far:

1. Setup `html, body {height: 100%;}`
2. Made `<html>` element a Grid.
3. Made `<body>` element a Grid.
4. Positioned  Grid element inside  Grid, *that is single column with single row*

   - `place-self: auto center;
     justify-self: center;`
5. Made a border around `<body>` element.

```css
 html, body {height: 100%;}
 
 html {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
 }
 
 body {
  border: solid 5px black;
  width: 50%;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  place-self: auto center;
  justify-self: center;
  
 }
 
 
 header { background-color: #0000b7;}
 main { background-color: blue;}
 footer { background-color:lightblue;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Home Page</title>
 <style>
   
 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header></header>
 <main>
 
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you be more clear about where the border should be? maybe a screenshot ?

Comment: Seems like the `<body>` is doing what you want. Maybe use `min-width` instead, so that way it can keep expanding?

Comment: Well, I can't just keep looking at every element inside grid and check if it is facing the direction I want it to be bordered. I need for the design to auto-solve it without any intervention from complicated javascript or human brain.
It is nothing unusual to have a border around grid layout items. Which is impossible, that's why I convert <html> to grid for positioning <body> container (that is not additional container like a <div>, but exists in every html document) and then border it (the <body> tag).

Comment: @Sensoray, updated the question details. The width is okey. I meant the height. In the example of mine it is solved. What is not solved: as of looking the example of my output: the top of the border is not showing up - that is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `place-self:center` was making the body top rise slightly above the html doc. Using `place-self:auto center;` should fix that.

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}
 
 html {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
 }
 
 body {
  border: solid 5px black;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top:5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  place-self: auto center;
  justify-self: center;
  
 }
 
 
 header { background-color: #0000b7;}
 main { background-color: blue;}
 footer { background-color:lightblue;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Home Page</title>
 <style>
   
 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header></header>
 <main>
 
 </main>
 <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure how stackoverflow works, but there is ability to commit an edit on my question with a short description of change.
Also add a notice in the text itself about necessity of"auto" self-placement. 

BTW, I have used your fix, so there is no more need to edit my code. Thanks.

Comment: @user3789797 Yes , you should be able to make an edit and add a description of what you changed. If my answer is correct, please don't forget to click the checkmark and mark it as so!

Answer (score -2):

Here's a quick hack if you can't find something:

```
<header style="border:1fr 1fr 0 1fr"></header>
<main style="border:0 1fr 0 1fr"></main>
<footer style="border:0 1fr 1fr 1fr"></footer>
```

e.g. remove bottom border from `header`, top and bottom borders from `main`, and top border for `footer`. And make sure there's no margin between them. This should create a seamless border.